# Automatic Reference Counting is not releasing calloc

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, automatic-ref-counting

I am using ARC`in my application, for encoding the string i am using`calloc` while i am running the app in profile it shows an memory leak at calloc.

[image]

whether `ARC` will release `calloc` or not?

if no, why it is not releasing and how to release `calloc`?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately ARC manages memory only for objective-c objects, so in your case you have to handle memory management yourself.

To "release" calloced memory you need to call `free` on it when it is no longer used:

```
free(strResult);
```